# Xcode Crash after trying to apply texture to ColorSprite node

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to apply a texture image to a ColorSprite node in my GameScene.sks file and everytime I try to do this my xcode crashes instantly..

I have attempted to reload my sprites and restart computer and xcode but nothing is working...

This was working fine a bit ago, but this morning it just stopped working... What could the issue be?

**EDIT:** Interestingly, I tried completely different png images I downloaded from google and when i put a single image (no @2x/@3x) sks does not quit... however, when I try to put a @2x in the crash happens...

After fiddling with it for a while, it seems that xcode just does NOT like @2x or @3x file names.. I can add a normal named image ("player.png") for example but when I add the @2x.png it freaks out. It seems all I can do isdd one file in the 1x slot of assets folder named (player.png)

Comment: If the problem is solved, I suggest deleting the question. I would also recommend submitting a bug report to Apple; you seem to have a reasonable use case, and crashing is never the correct response.

Comment: I didn't solve it and Apple is taking forever to get back to my bug report...

Comment: Did you do the ultra mega clean? Shift+Command+Option+K

Comment: Yes, ended up resorting to downloading XCODE 8.3.. Hope this gets fixed soon..

Comment: Thanks Wil, this workaround fixed it for me.  Seems like this is still a bug in Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the latest version of xcode 10.1 on OSX Mojave

Comment: I have Xcode 10.1 (10B61) on Mojave and not solved yet.